# Producer: metadata refresh when leader goes down

Tags: apache-kafka

Until recently, I thought that the process for producers, leader election and metadata went like this:

1. Producer published to a leader broker that was down, which would fail.
2. Producer tried a few times (or zero, depending on config).
3. Eventually Producer would “fail” publishing that message.
4. That would trigger Producer contacting the brokers to fetch a new metadata block, so it could find the newer leader and continue.

However what I’m observing is the Producer blocking after exhausting the retries and not doing anything until the metadata refreshes “automatically”. This refresh would be based on the time configured in this property (from Apache's Kafka documentation):

**metadata.max.age.ms**: The period of time in milliseconds after which we force a refresh of metadata even if we haven't seen any partition leadership changes to proactively discover any new brokers or partitions.

So basically, if the Producer happens to block near to the time where the metadata will expire itself, the production would recover quickly. However if the Producer blocks a few seconds after the last automatic refresh has happened, considering the default for the property is 5 minutes, the Producer would be blocked pretty much all that time.

Is there something I’m missing or not understanding correctly?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have also experienced same. The only thing I understood is you have to be careful with `metadata.max.age.ms` property. If your Data processing is critical and you don't want to lose your messages due to leader selection not happening, try keeping `metadata.max.age.ms property` as low as possible. But it will increase metadata update overhead.